# Sort ArrayList by Date and set specific double date TextView Gone

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-recyclerview

i'm creating at the moment a todo list app for myself and i have the following problem.

My data come from an SQLite database, i write them in an ArrayList to use the data in a RecyclerView.[Picture of the structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkBpW.png). You can see the structure on the picture.

As you can see, I have 2 entries with the date of today (heute). I want that when i create a new entry and another entry with the same date already exists, the second TextView for the date is setVisibility(GONE); and directly under the first entry with the date. Has anyone a idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to group data by date, something like this:

Today

- TODO #1
- TODO #2

Yesterday

- TODO #2
- TODO #3

Then you'll need two layouts:

Layout 1:

- TextView that shows date or text (Today, Yesterday,ETC.)
- RecyclerView to list children

Layout 2:
- Basically the layout of each note that you added(Title, Content, Time)

Not sharing code because i don't have an ide at the moment, but this is the logic.

Comment: Hey Carlos! Ty for your answer :) My ArrayList is sorted by the Date with a Comparator. At the moment the TextView of the Date is inside my list items that are displayed in the RecyclerView. Do you want to say if i have e,g. 5 different dates I need 5 different RecyclerViews in Layout 1?

Comment: Hi @NealMcBeal i said "group" :) not sort
You need a structure like a dictionary where the key is the date and the value is an array of notes.

Comment: Ah something like this: ` if (dateOuput.equals(overdueString)) {
            Map<String, Doing> overdueMap = new HashMap<>();
            overdueMap.put("Overdue", doing);`? In the if statement i compare the date of the entry with the date of yesterday and then put it in a HashMap? How do i achieve this sorted RecyclerView?